# Running logic in separate thread still locks UI - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, midi, anonymous-class

I have developed a simple MIDI application that allows me to play MIDI notes, in order for the user to be able to interact with the UI whilst the MIDI sounds are playing I have put the logic necessary in an anonymous subclass like so:

```
public static void Play() 
{
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                if (!_sequencer.isRunning()) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        _sequencer.setSequence(_sequence);
                        _sequencer.start();
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        Logger.Add(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Although the music begins to play the UI still fails to respond when I click on a ComboBox for example, I have something similar working fine in C#.

Is there some sort of caveat to thread in Java that would explain the behaviour i'm seeing?

(The Java API I'm using if it helps - [javax.sound.midi](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html))

Thanks for your time.

**Edit:**

Click around the UI a little more and noticed something interesting; everything seems to work fine with exception to two ComboBoxes in the top left most corner, I've tried deleting them and replacing them but makes no difference. The boxes change to blue when clicked (as it would normally) but the drop down box does not appear below it and the colour does not return to it's default when focus is on another UI component. Could it be a bug introduced by NetBeans perhaps?

**Example:**

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Well after much trial and error I have finally found the cause of the problem, the threading works great. The problem was that NetBeans has somehow realigned my UI components which causes the Window to fill the screen, manually resizing and testing the ComboBoxes showed that they actually worked fine.

Thanks for everybodys feedback!

Comment: i would suspect your COmboBox initialization code, more than the MIDI code. To prove it to yourself, don't start the midi thread and see if the combo boxes are still messed up.

Comment: Are you on linux? Here's a wild guess: try adding -Dsun.awt.disablegrab=true  on the command line that starts the app.

Comment: I've updated my question with the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much trial and error I have finally found the cause of the problem, the threading works great. The problem was that NetBeans has somehow realigned my UI components which causes the Window to fill the screen, manually resizing and testing the ComboBoxes showed that they actually worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

What does the combo box do when it's clicked? Does it interact with the `_sequencer`? Furthermore, was your sequencer created on the UI thread? I would suspect that while you're invoking the start method on a separate thread, the sequencer still runs on the context where it was created (i.e. UI thread).

Try creating the sequencer on the playing thread (i.e. NOT the UI thread) and see if that frees up your UI.

Comment: @Jamie, great :)... at least you figured it out!